# Utilizo bien el MUTEX?

Tags: c++, hilos, raspberry-pi

Estoy programando una aplicación en RPi y C++.
Para manipular la acción de un servidor de streaming lo que hago es crear un par de flags y la idea es que esta se pueda leer/escribir desde diferentes threads. 
Hoy el programa esta asi:

```
/*
 * varglobales.cpp
 */

#include <mutex>

mutex ssmtx;
bool closess = false;
```

Otro fuente:

```
 /* streamingserver.cpp
 */

 using namespace std;

extern bool closess;
extern mutex ssmtx;

void CallFromServerStream(string ip)
{

int timedout = 300;

while (timedout != 0)
{
    timedout --;
    cout << "\n entro al While" << endl;

    ssmtx.lock();  // Sugerido en el post (no cambio la situación)
    if (closess == true)
    {
        timedout = 0;
        cout << "\nCLOSESS es TRUE!!!"<< endl;
        break;
    }
    ssmtx.unlock(); // Sugerido en el post (no cambio la situación)
    cout << "\nVariable CLOSESS: " << closess << endl;
    cout<< "\nVariable TIMEDOUT: " << timedout << endl;
    sleep(1);
}
}
```

El ultimo fuente involucrado:

```
/* usuarios.cpp
 */
#include <mutex>
#include "usuarios.h"

using namespace std;

extern mutex ssmtx;
extern bool closess;

string usuario::CloseStreaming()
{
    ssmtx.lock();
    cout<< "\nSSMTX bloqueó" << endl;
    closess = true;
    cout << "CLOSESS es:\t" << closess << endl;
    ssmtx.unlock();
    cout<< "\nSSMTX se desbloqueó" << endl;

    return "{STREAM_CLOSE_OK}";
}
```

El problema se presenta de la siguiente manera. 
El streaming server se ejecuta bien. entra al while y queda ahí observando el valor de closess cada un segundo. ahora bien, cuando el método CloseStreaming es llamado el while se clava. sin mas. Creo que estoy utilizando mal el mutex o la declaración de las var globales. pero no encuentro algún ejemplo especifico para seguirlo.

Comment: Hola, solo colocaste el mutex en un solo lugar, seria conveniente que bloquees el recurso en ambos lugares. Tambien te recomiendo que uses un lock_guard para no tener ningun deadlock

Comment: @ReymonARG si usa un mutex en un solo sitio, no es posible tener un deadlock a no ser que se llame `CloseStreaming` desde dos hilos diferentes. Bien sugerido lo de [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) por cierto.

Comment: "seria conveniente que bloquees el recurso en ambos lugares." Esto se hace con el mismo mutex, osea lo hago con ssmtx??? ; 'CloseStreaming' se llama en un solo thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varios fallos:

1 - Estas definiendo variables globales en un .h , con lo cual las estas definiendo varias veces. (tantas como se incluya el .h por los .cpp)

2 - Las defines como "static", con lo cual, no se ven desde fuera. Realmente en tu codigo hay dos booleanos y dos mutex.

HAZ:

- Borra el .h
- En un fichero .cpp declara las vars de verdad (sin static y sin extern).
- Y en el otro fichero .cpp declara las variables con extern.

Y te funcionara.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, modifiqué el código como dijiste pero la situación del mutex sigue igual.. voy a editar la publicación para actualizar el código.